# list of classes in python 3

Tags: python, class

We can do something like below in C:

```
struct teams {
char team_name[100];
int team_point[100];


}

struct teams teams1[100];
```

We get array of struct in this way, is it somehow possible in Python? Thanks

Comment: You don't need to do that in Python (it's dynamic!), but you can do it if you want to - what's your use case?

Comment: Why would you have an array of points within the struct?

Comment: It's not an `array` of `struct`s, however, it's a `struct` of `array`s.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Team(object):
    def __init__(self, name, points):
        self.name = name
        self.points = points

teams = []
teams.append(Team('Chicago Bulls', [85, 75, 93, 10]))
```

Since Python is dynamic, nothing prevents you from assigning arbitrary values to object properties (object instances behave mostly like namespaces), but lacking a pedantic compiler screaming about type mismatches has some advantages.